# jQuery don't select a-tag in p-tag

Tags: jquery, replace, children

Hello I try to style numbers in p-tag different and prevent the styling within the a-tag. jQuery adds span-tag called number to the p-tag but should not add this within the href of a-tag.

```
<div class="ce_text">
  <p>1234 example <a class="link" href="http://www.abc.de/123/def" target="_blank">www.abc.de/123/def</a> goes on 567.</p>
  <a href="http://www.999.com">Link 999 (no function)</a>
  <p>1234 example <a class="link" href="http://www.abc.de/123/def" target="_blank">www.abc.de/123/def</a> goes on 567.</p>
</div>
```

The number in the p-tag should contain a span-tag, the a-tag should not:

```
RIGHT: <p><span="number">123</span>text goes here.</p>

WRONG: <a href="http://www.abc.de/<span class="number"123">123<span>/def">link</a>
```

My approach won't work.

My fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/huppen/7f1ccvy5/6/

Any tipps to solve my problem are appreciated.

**Problem solved with the approach from Rejith R Krishnan (THANKS!):**

```
$(".ce_text p").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; //nodeType 3 is the text nodes
}).each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).replaceWith(function(){
      return this.nodeValue.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>')
    });
});
```

**[Working JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f1ccvy5/10/)**

Comment: Your selector says `select all <p> tags from .ce_text that are not <a> tag` - illogical selector.

Comment: Hey is there a logical selector to solve my problem?

Comment: Rejith R Krishnan provided a working approach with contents() filter() to select text nodes in the element: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37521803/3104330

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach. Using `contents()` and `filter()` select the text nodes in the element, then replaces them with new HTML.

```
$(".ce_text p").contents().filter(function(){ 
  return this.nodeType == 3; //nodeType 3 is the text nodes
}).each(function(i, v) {
    $(this).replaceWith(function(){
      return this.nodeValue.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="number">$1</span>')
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/7f1ccvy5/10/)

Comment: Thank you Rejith R Krishnan your approach is working :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach this by this query selector, on the other hand, you can make the text inside of the `p` tag within a `span` and use it in the selector.

**[Running Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7f1ccvy5/8/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to set span tags manually in all p tags. Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this solution. I tested on fiddler and it works, but isn't elegant:

```
$.each($('.ce_text p'), function(i, el){
    var txt = $(el).find("A").text();
    txt = txt.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class=number>$1</span>');
    txt = txt.substring(txt.indexOf("<span"));
    txt = txt.substring(0, txt.indexOf("</span>") + 7);

    $(el).find("A").after(txt);
    $(el).find("A").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your approach. This will remove the a-tags but they should stay. Only the span-tag within the a-tag should be removed. It's tricky I guess …